# How can i set style attribute dynamic?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am using this code, to add dynamic styles.

```js
function translateRange(
    input,
    inputMin,
    inputMax,
    outputMin,
    outputMax
) {
    let inputMinA = Math.min(inputMin, input);
    let inputMaxA = Math.max(inputMax, input);

    return (
        outputMin +
        ((outputMax - outputMin) * (input - inputMinA)) /
            (inputMaxA - inputMinA)
    );
};

function animate(node, params) {
  for (var key in params) {
    if (key !== 'trigger') {
      let value = translateRange(params.trigger, params[key].start, params[key].end, params[key].from, params[key].to);
      node.setAttribute("style", `${key}: ${value}`);
    }
  }
}

let block = document.querySelector('#block');
window.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
    animate(block, {trigger: window.scrollY, opacity: {start: 0, end: 200, from: 1, to: 0}, rotate: {start: 0, end: 200, from: 0, to: 90} });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 300vh;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
}

#block {
  height: 80px;
  width: 80px;
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div id="block" />
</div>
```

The Problem is that the `rotate` prop not working in this case. Only normal props like `opactiy` are working in this case. How can i improve my `animation()` function, so `opactiy` and `transform: rotate` are working together? Any ideas?

Comment: Because you keep overwriting the style with individual styles

Comment: @epascarello opacity works, but not transform, because `rotate:` is not a valid style prop. Any ideas, how can i improve my function, to get it working?

Comment: Have you tried? `Object.assign(node.style, { [key]: value });`

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl `node.style[key] = value;` works now